# Python Send Data to Websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm trying to stream my global mouse cursor position to a web client using a super simple websocket.

I've got both of those things happening, and my client (in JS) works fine, but I don't know how to connect them; I want to send a websocket message whenever on `move()` is called, but everything I've tried throws an error.

This code prints out mouse locations and runs the websocket, but how can I get the two to 'talk' to each other?

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from pynput import mouse

def onmove(x, y):
    print(x,y)

async def socket_handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"Received {message}")

        resp = f'WS Message Was: {message}'
        await websocket.send(resp)


listener = mouse.Listener(on_move = onmove)
listener.start()

start_server = websockets.serve(socket_handler, "127.0.0.1", 5000)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I feel like there must be a really obvious answer and I just don't understand async and event loops well enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got multiple threads going there with your pynput and asyncio stuff.  To share data across threads, you need a thread-safe container.  One option for that is python's [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) module.

A much better option-- from an asyncio perspective--, as pointed out in the comments by user4815162342, is to use asyncio's [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) and a call_soon_threadsafe on asyncio's event_loop from your other thread.  Here's an example of that:

```
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
from pynput import mouse

q = asyncio.Queue()

def onmove(x, y):
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(q.put_nowait, (x,y))

async def socket_handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await q.get()
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(message))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
start_server = websockets.serve(socket_handler, "127.0.0.1", 5000)
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)

listener = mouse.Listener(on_move = onmove)
listener.start()
loop.run_forever()
```

Old example using a standard queue.Queue.

**example_server.py**

```
import asyncio
import queue
import json
import websockets
from pynput import mouse

q = queue.SimpleQueue()

def onmove(x, y):
    try:
        print("Putting: {0}".format((x,y)))
        q.put((x,y), block=False)
    except q.Full:
        print("Dropped coords: {0}".format((x,y)))

async def getCoords():
    coords = None
    try:
        coords = q.get(block=False)
    except queue.Empty:
        # print("QUEUE EMPTY")
        pass
    return coords

async def socket_handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await getCoords()
        if message:
            await websocket.send(json.dumps(message))

listener = mouse.Listener(on_move = onmove)
listener.start()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
start_server = websockets.serve(socket_handler, "127.0.0.1", 5000)
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
loop.run_forever()
```

**example_client.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5000");
   exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
         var coords = JSON.parse(event.data);
         $('#x').html(coords[0]);
         $('#y').html(coords[1]);
   };
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>X: <span id="x"></span></p>
<p>Y: <span id="y"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is exactly what I needed, I had built a different version all in a single thread and it was horribly inefficient... I've added queue clearing and a sleep timer to the while loop and it uses massively less resources than my single-threaded one.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `socket_handler` will busy-loop if the mouse doesn't move. You can improve it by using `asyncio.Queue` instead. Then `getCoord()` can just `await q.get()`, and `onmove` can be thread-safe by using `event_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(q.put_nowait, (x, y))`.